# implementation of string class

Tags: c++

I'm interested in the implementation of the `reverse iterator with rbegin(), rend() and operator++ of the class string`, I can't find it in google, how can I do it? thanks in advance for any help or any link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could look in the implementation header files.  (e.g. `/usr/include/c++/4.1.2/string` on Linux).  This will typically just pull in a load of other headers where the real meat lies, such as `bits/basic_string.h`.

I don't know where they reside for e.g. VC++, but you can usually just get Intellisense to find it by creating a `std::string`, selecting it and pressing F12.

Comment: For VC++, it's something like C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include (just search for header name).

Answer (score 0):

There is a basic implementation of [reverse_iterator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/reverse_iterator/) in the STL.

It is templatized by the `Iterator` to be reverted.

The idea is quite simple, if you look at a range:

```
[first, second, .... last]
   ^                         ^
 begin                      end
 rend                     rbegin
```

There is extra-work done, compared to a pure reverse iterator using this implementation, since for each dereference, you need to copy the iterator you hold, decrement it, and then dereference it.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse iteration for bidirectional iterators is implemented in the `std::reverse_iterator` template.

The implementation of reverse iterators for `std::string` doesn't take more than:

```
template <xxx>
class basic_string
{
public:
    typedef std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator> const_reverse_iterator;
    typedef std::reverse_iterator<iterator> reverse_iterator;

    reverse_iterator rbegin() { return reverse_iterator(this->end()); }
    const_reverse_iterator rbegin() const { return const_reverse_iterator(this->end()); }
    reverse_iterator rend() { return reverse_iterator(this->begin()); }
    const_reverse_iterator rend() const { return const_reverse_iterator(this->begin()); }
    //...
};
```

(Copied from GCC's implementation.)